# How to disable camera and microphone popup alert via Selenium WebDriver tests?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, chrome-options

Currently, I have tests which perform a specific test flow however this specific flow causes Chrome to present the user (Tests) with a microphone, camera alert popups:

[image]

I need a way to disable the alerts via Selenium Webdriver / Java, I have attempted to use Chrome options, with no luck; example code:

```
ChromeOptions op = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic", 1);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera", 1);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 1);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);
op.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
RemoteWebDriver remoteDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(REMOTE_HUB_URL), op);
```

Even solely tried the following with no luck:

```
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the "2" value for that.
Code:

```
...
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic", 2);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera", 2);
...
```

PS: The value "1" is used for allowing the option, "2" -- for blocking.

I hope it helps you!